# Generic implementation of processor cache using LRU with varying association sizes

Tags: java, caching, data-structures

So I'm doing this project in Java to simulate CPU cache hit/misses and the associations can range from 1 (Direct mapped), 2, 4, 8, 16 (fully associative)

It utilizes Least Recently Used (LRU) scheme to determine what to get rid of in the cache if we need to make room. For the purpose of this exercise no third-party libraries may be used,  but any version of Java can be used.

For direct mapped it's easy enough to just use a LinkedHashMap to set up the sets

But am I able to adapt this to different association sizes, say 4.

Set 1 0000 0001 0002 0003

Set 2 0000 0001 0002 0003

Set 3 0000 0001 0002 0003

Set 4 0000 0001 0002 0003

I'm thinking of just using a LinkedHashMap with a doublylinkedlist, but may be overcomplicating things?

Am I taking a sledgehammer to an egg here? Any thoughts are welcome.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Node>

class Node{
    String value;
    Node prev;
    Node next;

    public Node(String value){
        this.value=value;
    }
}
```

Comment: LHM has direct lru support via `removeEldestEntry` and the `accessOrder` flag. It sounds like you would have a list of LHMs of size M and bound the LHM to size N. Then hash to the key to determine the list index to work with that LHM. Of course write some unit tests to verify your logic simulates the expected output, e.g. from your book's example problems.

Comment: "Then hash to the key to determine the list index to work with that LHM". Can you elaborate on this? So we have List<LHM<k,v>>, what am I supposed to do with the key in LHM to ensure that it's not overwriting another value with the same key that's not the LRU.

Comment: Just insert into a bounded LHM and it will evict the LRU for you. Something like list.get(key.hashCode() % list.size()).put(key, value).

Comment: Alright. The last problem I'm running into is printing output. If the association size is 4 and there are no values, I want it to print something. I've modified get(Object key) to return a default value, but I'm not sure how to iterate through non-existent keys to get the message.

Comment: LHM has iterators via `keySet`, `values`, or `entrySet`. If the LHM is less than 4, you could simply print defaults for the remaining spaces (e.g. 4 - map.size()).